# Is gvfs capable of connecting to WebDAV shares with Digest authentication?

Tags: authentication, webdav, gvfs

On Ubuntu 12.04 I try to connect to a WebDAV share on the local network, from Nautilus (over http, not https).

This works with cadaver and davfs (both of which seem to depend on a library called neon to do their work).

However it does not work with gvfs: Nautilus displays 'Error: not a WebDAV-enabled share'.

On the Apache2 server, `access.log` shows `"OPTIONS /site HTTP/1.1" 200 229 "-" "gvfs/1.12.1"`
then nothing.

The configuration follows this writeup: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Apache2WebDavDigestAUTH

Is it a known gvfs bug ?

Comment: Well, it fails with the same error in Nautilus if *Basic authentication* is required instead of Digest.